# Unable to draw on 3D model but can do so on Texture Map. Also, no Texture Paint UVs detected

Tags: texture-painting

Can anyone advise on this problem: I'm unable to paint directly on the 3D model, can only do so on the image texture/ texture map. When I try drawing on the 3d model, the whole model changes into a weird tint/shade. Also the strokes drawn on the Texture Map is not reflected on my model. I've tried to trouble shoot by adding fills etc and it seems like the Texture map and the material on the 3D model are the same so I'm not sure what's wrong. Have added the shading node map in case someone can use that to diagnose the problem.

[Video showing the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQP8s.jpg)

I also noticed that I don't have any Texture Paint UVs, after I did a [side by side comparison](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ApSk6.jpg) with the tutorial I was following. Could this be the problem, and how do I "add" these texture paint UVs?

Comment: hello could you please pack your image and share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: For texture paint, you need a valid UV map. Have you UV unwrapped your pizza slice? Depending on how you've created it the UV map might be missing. The donut is created from a torus which comes with a default UV map. For a quick test to go to the *UV Editing* workspace, select everything in the 3D Viewport (right side), and press U & select *Smart UV Project*. Then you should see a UV map in the UV editor (left side). Blenderguru also has an "Anvil" tutorial series that covers UV unwrapping & texture baking -> https://youtu.be/scPSP_U858k